# how to remove spaces, brackets and " from nsarray

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsarray

I have an array where i am trying to remove the access spaces, brackets and " from the nsarray in order to use `componentsSeparatedByString:@";"`

```
NSArray *paths = [dic valueForKey:@"PATH"];

    for(NSString *s in paths)
    {
        NSLog(@"String: %@", s);
    }

String: (
"29858,39812;29856,39812;29800,39819;29668,39843;29650,39847;29613,39855;29613,39855;29613,39856;29605,39857;29603,39867;29603,39867;29599,39892;29596,39909;29587,39957;29571,40018;29563,40038;29560,40043"
)
```

this is the output give as show there are spaces, brackets and " how could i remove them 
?
As this line is juz a string inside that array `"29858,39812;29856,39812;29800,39819;29668,39843;29650,39847;29613,39855;29613,‌​39855;29613,39856;29605,39857;29603,39867;29603,39867;29599,39892;29596,39909;295‌​87,39957;29571,40018;29563,40038;29560,40043" this line is a string inside the path array` and i try using `componentsSeparatedByString:@";"` it could not be spilt all there are spaces brackets and " inside.

Answer (score 3):

Try stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:

```
NSCharacterSet *charsToTrim = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"()  \n\""];
s = [s stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charsToTrim];
```

Comment: i use the codes in the for loop but it got an error.
`-[__NSArrayM stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9a8bc0`

Comment: @user1495988 that means your *s contained array. not string

Comment: Well, then it's not a string you've got in your array, but an other array. Try this in your loop: `NSLog(NSStringFromClass([s class]));`

Comment: a warning message `Format string is not a string literal(potentially insecure)`

Comment: That's no problem. Or try: `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([s class]));`

Comment: `"29858,39812;29856,39812;29800,39819;29668,39843;29650,39847;29613,39855;29613,39855;29613,39856;29605,39857;29603,39867;29603,39867;29599,39892;29596,39909;29587,39957;29571,40018;29563,40038;29560,40043"` this line is a string inside the `path` array

Comment: This won't work for unwanted characters in the middle of a string -- it only trims from the ends.

Comment: Yes, but from the log he posted, there are only brackets on the beginning and the end. But it's an array apparently anyway.

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

```
s = [s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@";"
                                     withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

it separates the numbers for you and you can work with them as i.e. `NSInteger` values.

```
NSString *_inputString = @"29858,39812;29856,39812;29800,39819;29668,39843;29650,39847;29613,39855;29613,39855;29613,39856;29605,39857;29603,39867;29603,39867;29599,39892;29596,39909;29587,39957;29571,40018;29563,40038;29560,40043";
NSString *_setCommonSeparator = [_inputString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@";" withString:@","];
NSArray *_separetedNumbers = [_setCommonSeparator componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

for (NSString *_currentNumber in _separetedNumbers) {
    NSInteger _integer = [_currentNumber integerValue];
    NSLog(@"number : %d", _integer);
}
```