# Removing parentheses from the string in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to remove all the parentheses in my string in iOS. Saw this stackoverflow post: [how to remove spaces, brackets and " from nsarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986337/how-to-remove-spaces-brackets-and-from-nsarray)

The answer:

```
NSCharacterSet *charsToTrim = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"()"];
s = [s stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charsToTrim];
```

But this just removes one bracket which is ( from mystring. How to remove all of them?

My code looks like this:

```
NSCharacterSet *charsToTrim = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"( )"];
attributedLabel.text = [attributedLabel.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charsToTrim];
NSLog(@"%@",attributedLabel.text);
```

Need some guidance on this...

Comment: The problem is, that the trim method only checks the beginning and end of the string, not what's inside.

Comment: Weird thing. Your code is working perfectly with me. `NSString *s = @"( from mystring. How to ) remove ( all of them?)";
    NSCharacterSet *charsToTrim = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"( )"];
    s = [s stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charsToTrim];
    NSLog(@"%@", s);`

Comment: I am passing the text to attributedLabel from plist file.. could it be a reason?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try using
`[[attributedLabel.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];`
instead.

Comment: firstly thanks for replying.. I tried this as well, but it is not remove the brackets.. is it because of the I am passing the text from plist file?

Comment: @lakesh, are you trying to remove brackets "[]", as you ask in the text, or parentheses "()", as your code samples demonstrate? Is the code even running (try putting a breakpoint on the relevant line)?

Comment: Try: NSLog(@"%@", [[@"This (is a) test." stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""]); It should log "This is a test."

Comment: Then it sounds like your issue occurs elsewhere. If you're loading from a plist file, are you sure that your code doesn't reload from the file after you've set the text to the stripped string?

Comment: No I don't. I get the plist file as a dictionary and one of the keys refers to the string that I am passing to attributedLabel...

Comment: Clearly the code snippets you've been given DO remove parentheses. One possibility if it's not working for you is that they are Unicode characters that look like parentheses, but aren't the standard ones.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4.2 use `replacingOccurrences`

For eg. to get Pizza from (Pizza)

```
let foodWithParentheses = "(Pizza)"

let pizzaWithoutParen = foodWithParentheses.replacingOccurrences(of: "(", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: ")", with: "")

print(pizzaWithoutParen)
// output: Pizza
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code is working

```
NSString *str=[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"string"];
NSLog(@"%@",[[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply do this like below:

```
NSString *finalStr = [initialStr stringByReplacingOccurenceOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
finalStr = [finalStr stringByReplacingOccurenceOfString:@")" withString:@""];
```

This will remove all the parentheses from the string:I found this answer on this developer's [blog](http://blackberrymastercracks.blogspot.in)