# Removing brackets from UILabel in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, nsmutableattributedstring

I posted this question yesterday:[Removing parentheses from the string in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789359/removing-parentheses-from-the-string-in-ios). But I am not still able to remove the brackets from the  label.

Not sure what my mistake. Spent the whole night figuring, still not able to do so.

I am using TTTAttributedLabel. My code looks like this:

```
-(TTTAttributedLabel*)setItalicTextForLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel*)attributedLabel fontSize:(float)Size
{
    [attributedLabel setText:[self.infoDictionary objectForKey:@"description"] afterInheritingLabelAttributesAndConfiguringWithBlock:^NSMutableAttributedString *(NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString)
    {
        NSRange stringRange = NSMakeRange(0, [mutableAttributedString length]);
        NSRegularExpression *regexp = ParenthesisRegularExpression();
        UIFont *italicSystemFont = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:Size];
        DLog(@"%@",italicSystemFont.fontName);
        CTFontRef italicFont = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)italicSystemFont.fontName, italicSystemFont.pointSize, NULL);
        [regexp enumerateMatchesInString:[mutableAttributedString string] options:0 range:stringRange usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
            if (italicFont) {
                [mutableAttributedString removeAttribute:(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName range:result.range];
                [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName value:(__bridge id)italicFont range:result.range];
                CFRelease(italicFont);
            }
        }];

        return mutableAttributedString;
    }];
    [[attributedLabel.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"]" withString:@""];
    return attributedLabel;
}
```

Still not able to remove the brackets. Can anyone point out my mistake? Would really appreciate the help.

Comment: I think you mean brackets, you are trying to remove this char, "[" right

Comment: said it wrongly. edited the question.

Comment: I see what you are trying to do.  What I did was modify `MGMushParser` (a library on GitHub) to get the result I wanted.  It will parse certain "tags" (in your case [italic text]) and replace it with some attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the last two line with this two:

```
[attributedLabel setText:[[attributedLabel.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"]" withString:@""]];
return attributedLabel;
```

The methods that begins with string... does not change the string itself only returns a new string that is changed.

By the way, NSString objects are immutable. If you want to change strings you can use NSMutableString, the below implementation use only the NSMutabeString, that you are already using in the block.

-

Try This:

```
-(TTTAttributedLabel*)setItalicTextForLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel*)attributedLabel fontSize:(float)Size
{
    [attributedLabel setText:[self.infoDictionary objectForKey:@"description"] afterInheritingLabelAttributesAndConfiguringWithBlock:^NSMutableAttributedString *(NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString)
    {
        NSRange stringRange = NSMakeRange(0, [mutableAttributedString length]);
        NSRegularExpression *regexp = ParenthesisRegularExpression();
        UIFont *italicSystemFont = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:Size];
        DLog(@"%@",italicSystemFont.fontName);
        CTFontRef italicFont = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)italicSystemFont.fontName, italicSystemFont.pointSize, NULL);
        [regexp enumerateMatchesInString:[mutableAttributedString string] options:0 range:stringRange usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
            if (italicFont) {
                [mutableAttributedString removeAttribute:(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName range:result.range];
                [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName value:(__bridge id)italicFont range:result.range];
                CFRelease(italicFont);
                NSRange range1 = NSMakeRange (result.range.location, 1); 
                NSRange range2 = NSMakeRange (result.range.location + result.range.length-2, 1); 
                [mutableAttributedString replaceCharactersInRange:range1 withString:@""];
                [mutableAttributedString replaceCharactersInRange:range2 withString:@""];
            }
        }];
        return mutableAttributedString;
    }];
    return attributedLabel;
}
```

Comment: it removes the brackets but the italic font is removed... now how do you ensure that the both is preserved...

Comment: Put the line that set the text in the attributedlabel in the beginning of the method.

Comment: I am using the brackets to differentiate the italic text and non-italic text.

Comment: I updated the answer to match better your question.

Comment: tried your edit. gives me an error of "Sending NSString* to parameter of incompatible type 'NSRange'"

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I forgot that it expects a range, chang the code to row it must look, maybe you need to adjust a thing or two, but I believe that you got the idea.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30799/discussion-between-lakesh-and-ggrana)